# Use and bind {{input}} inside a component

Tags: ember.js

Sorry if this is a silly question. I am in the middle of the steepest part of the Ember learning curve and trying to get a simple app going as a learning tool for myself, and my google-fu is failing me in understanding how to do this;

I have a component that is basically a list of model objects with some filtering options. The filter option relevant to this discussion is a free-text search. I want to have an {{input}} that is is bound to some value that affects the result list whenever it is updated.

```
{{input type=text value=filterString}}
```

In my poor understanding of Ember, I would have bound the value of the input to a string property, and have my filteredMatches computed property depend on that. However, if I define that property as such:

```
filteredMatches: Ember.computed.filter('matches', 'filterString', function(match, index, array) {
```

I get an error in the console log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: callback.call is not a function
```

If I remove the reference to 'filterString', it works as expected, but of course the filtering is not updated when I type something into the input.

So with my limited knowledge of Ember, I am stuck with this; Is the input actually binding to filterString on the controller, not the component? I do not use explicit controllers as I understand they will be going away. If that is the case, how can I have a computed property in my component depend on a controller property?

If that is not the case (i.e. controllers are not involved), how can I bind the input to a component property and react to value changes accordingly?

```
ember -v
version: 2.3.0-beta.2
node: 5.6.0
npm: 2.14.10
os: win32 x64
```

Thanks for any help, and again, sorry if this question is stupid!

Edit: Both answers by Kitler and Lux were enlightening and helpful. I chose the one by Lux since it came with a concrete solution, but I wish I could have accepted both. To make up for it I will definitely join the Slack channel. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ember.computed.filter` has the signature `(dependentKey, callback)`. [Checkout the documentation.](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_filter)

The second argument *must* be a function. For your use case use a normal Computed Property:

```
filteredMatches: Ember.computed('matches', 'filterString', {
    get() {
        return get(this, 'matches').filter(item => item.indexOf(get(this, 'filterString')) >= 0)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In times like these where you are unable to find an answer on google the [API documentation](http://emberjs.com/api) is the place to be, if you look at the docs for [Ember.computed.filter](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_filter) you will notice it only takes 1 dependent key.

In order to deal with your problem is to use `Ember.computed` along with one of the `Ember.Array` [filter](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_filter) functions.

In the future for such questions consider joining us on the [ember community slack](https://ember-community-slackin.herokuapp.com/) channel.